# How to parse Multiple RSS feeds in SwiftRSS Library in swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, rss

I want to parse Multiple RSS feed at a time in swift. i have done it using the NSXMLParser. I have come across this swiftRSS https://github.com/tibo/SwiftRSS library for the same purpose.but can i Parse Multiple feed as same time which should in sorted order with latest news on top. OR Is there any other library that can be used for same purpose.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a library that lets you parse multiple feeds, have you considered using an API which does this and yiels you the results directy? [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com) provides this.